# How does the `guid` in dynamic profiles in Windows Terminal work to find the target?

Tags: powershell, wsl-2, windows-terminal

I've worked with Windows Terminal for a while. Recently, I wanted to add some additional 3rd party command line tools into [dynamic profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/dynamic-profiles) in Windows Terminal.

It must be successful if using `commandline`. But if not used, how does the Windows Terminal find our target items?

Maybe out of curiosity, I cannot understand the automatically created profiles, such as `WSL` or `PowerShell`:

```json
{
    "guid": "{574e775e-4f2a-5b96-ac1e-a2962a402336}",
    "hidden": false,
    "name": "PowerShell",
    "source": "Windows.Terminal.PowershellCore"
},
{
    "guid": "{d7b20cea-47a9-518c-95a4-c8bd91e2e1c6}",
    "hidden": false,
    "name": "Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS",
    "source": "CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu22.04LTS_79rhkp1fndgsc"
},
```

I've done some ablation experiments and found the following points:

- If I comment out the `name` and `source` of `PowerShell`, but retain the `guid`, this profile will still work.
- If I comment out the `guid` of `PowerShell`, but retain the other settings, this profile will **not** work.
- If I comment out the `name` and `source` of `Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS`, but retain the `guid`, this profile will still work.
- If I comment out the `guid` of `Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS`, but retain other settings, this profile will still work.

My problems are:

- How can Windows Terminal find the target by the [GUID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/profile-advanced#unique-identifier)?
- Why in the above samples, can `Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS` still be found when given only the `source` and `name` and without `guid`?
- If so, why can't, in the above sample, the `PowerShell` be found when given only the `source` and `name` and without `guid`?